# how to terminate a process via key stroke

Tags: bash, shell, tshark

I have this function on my bash script:

```
sudo tshark -i eth0 -T fields -e ip.src -e dns.qry.name -Y "dns.qry.name~." -q 1>>log.txt 2>/dev/null &
while true
do
cat log.txt
done
```

it is capturing ips and domain names in live mode and save them into log file.
how can configure this live mode to be terminated by pressing a key?

Comment: Why do you have a loop and not simply `tail -f`? Also, `CTRL-C` already terminates your foreground process

Answer (score 0):

Using `tee` to watch log and send the command to background, then read input to terminate script

```
tshark -i eth0 -T fields -e ip.src -e dns.qry.name -Y "ip" -q 2>/dev/null | tee log.txt  & 
read -n1 c && echo "Got key $c"
exit
```

Note: running the command in a console will terminate it :-p

Comment: works great :)what this tee command does?

Comment: `read from standard input and write to standard output and files`. You can accept the answer and/or upvote it if you wish :-)

Comment: @AlexZarankin: see `man tee` for more details about `tee`.